# Ignore `OutOfBoundsException` error when watermark grower of source image

Tags: image, yii2, watermark

In `Yii2` and core `yii\imagine\Image` class, When use this command:

```
Image::watermark('image.jpg', 'watermark.jpg')->save('image.jpg');
```

If dimension of watermark, grower of source image, return this error:

```
Exception 'Imagine\Exception\OutOfBoundsException' with message 'Cannot paste image of the given size at the specified position, as it moves outside of the current image's box'
```

It's fine. But how can ignore this error, so new image will be create but the part of watermark that outside of the image box is hidden and removed.

Comment: I guess if the framework function doesn't allow watermarks that exceed the image bounds, you're going to have to either resize the watermark first, or paste it on with your own code.

Comment: so what you want to achieve is if the watermark is greater it should still create the image with that specific watermark?

Comment: do mark the answer if it worked for you

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I'm working on it.

Comment: ok no issue, take your time

Answer (score 0):

There is no ignoring the `Exceptions` thats why they are called by that name, The Exception is thrown from the `paste(ImageInterface $image, PointInterface $start);` method

```
$size = $image->getSize();
if (!$this->getSize()->contains($size, $start)) {
    throw new OutOfBoundsException('Cannot paste image of the given size at the specified position, as it moves outside of the current image\'s box');
}
```

that is called in the `Image::watermark` function. It is restricted and not allowed so you cannot Ignore it.

You can ignore/suppress notices or warnings but you can `catch` the exceptions and do something to fix it or present the error to the user

```
try{
    \yii\imagine\Image::watermark ( 'img/image.png' , 'img/logo.jpg' );
} catch (\Imagine\Exception\OutOfBoundsException $ex) {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error',$ex->getMessage()) ;
}
```

Or if the exception occurs resize the watermark image smaller than the base image and call the `Image::watermark` again.

## `EDIT`

You can do something like below what i was talking about suppose you have an `actionWatermark()` where you are creating the watermark image

```
public function actionWatermark() {
    $image='image.jpg';
    $watermark= 'watermark.jpg';

    try {
        //call watermark function
        $this->watermark ($image,$watermark);
    } catch ( \Imagine\Exception\OutOfBoundsException $ex ) {
        
        $img = \yii\imagine\Image::getImagine ();
        //get the base image dimensions
        $size=$img->open ( $image )->getSize();
        //resize the watermark image
        $resized=\yii\imagine\Image::resize ( $watermark , $size->getWidth () , $size->getHeight (),TRUE);
        
        //call again
        $this->watermark ($image,$resized);
    }
    
}

private function watermark($image,$watermark) {
    \yii\imagine\Image::watermark ( $image , $watermark )->save ( 'image.jpg' );
}
```

Comment: This is just error handling, but I want effective watermark with remove the part of that can not be cover the original image.

Comment: see the edit part what i was talking about @NabiK.A.Z.